Select region key-binding not working
My emacs was set up by an expert and I just took it and used it. I am sorry that I can only phrase the question only as a complete newbie. I use macOS Monterey version 12.6.3.
Previously, I could use C-SPC and then command+< (hold the shift key and press the button with both < and ,) to select the region between the cursor and the beginning of the buffer. However, I recently discovered it does not work. If I now press C-SPC, it will no longer display "Mark set" at the bottom of the buffer(previously it did). If I press shift + upper arrow, it will display "Mark set" and make the intended highlight.
If I press shift+<, it will display "Mark set" and go to the very beginning of the buffer, but does not do anything. I do not expect it to display "Mark set"!
What might be the problem and how can I make an attempt to fix it? Is there anything I can try in my init.el? I can find and edit it.

If this is not happening using emacs -Q (as I suspect), then my suggestion will be bisecting the init.el provided to you by the expert user (or, well, just ask them about this behaviour).

@ManuelUberti May I please confirm what is meant by "Using emacs -Q"? I assume it means running "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -Q" in the terminal. I tried it, and an Emacs buffer does pop up.

Yes, you're perfectly right, and what you get is Emacs running with no custom configuration in place. So basically you get a clean environment to try to reproduce your problem.

@ManuelUberti Is there any tutorial of the flow of debugging init.el from there? The window pops up is written with ";; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer." I do not know where to go from here. Any directions would be appreciated.

My point is trying to do the same C-SPC you tried with your init.el and check if in emacs -Q works as you expect. If so, then "something" in your init.el is causing the issue you are experiencing. Bisecting your init.el means commenting out pieces of code, launching Emacs (as you normally do, not with emacs -Q, because you want to pick up your init.el) and pressing C-SPC to see if it works as you expect. Then try again with other code commented out and so and so forth until you get to the code causing the issue.

Thank you very much for the explanation. But in the emacs opens with -Q, nothing actually works as well. Nothing happens with C-SPC as well, and command+< does not even go back to the beginning of the file. Does this information indicate anything more?

If I press C-SPC in emacs -Q I can see the message Mark set and if I do M-< (Alt-< on my keyboard) the cursor goes at the top of the buffer with the text selected as I would expect. If you have problems with emacs -Q as well, then it's very hard for me to help.

@ManuelUberti I see. It is indeed tricky then. Thank you very much for keep helping! I will try ask around.

@ManuelUberti: For future reference, there is a standard question and answer on debugging init problems: How do I troubleshoot Emacs problems?. It contains a detailed description on bisecting one's init file. I recommend referring to it, instead of trying to describe the process in a comment.

Thanks for the reference, @NickD.
